# How to create a camera-based shader mask?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, masking

I'm looking to create a shader in Eevee where object A inside of object B casts a ray/projection/mask over a set distance towards the camera to mask out its shape in object B. Here's what I've managed so far:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

This works to an extent, however it's important that the projected silhouette of object A on object B is sharp and accurate. For this example I've used face corner values. While it could be made sharper by kicking up the subdivisions, this is not ideal. Here's how it looks up close:

[image: 4]

(In the past I've used compositing to achieve the effect I'm looking for but with that method I would have over 20 render layers per character, since the character had to be cut into parts for the masking to function as intended.)

Though my understanding of the Cycles engine is limited I think it might be better suited to create a shader like this, but I hope to stick with the Eevee engine since it works well in my workflow.

If anything is unclear, let me know. Any suggestions are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is that holdout "inverted"?

Comment: Are you asking if it would be like an inverted holdout? I think so, in the sense that it would reveal what's in front of it rather than hide what's behind it.
But it should only do this over a certain distance, like with the model.

Comment: Hi, Zoukeau  ..  it's not obvious why a pass with the masking-object alone, mixing between  scene-with-masked-object and scene-without-masked-object would require so many render-layers?

Comment: Ray Direction should be a direction, not a camera location. This means that it should be subtraction from position from camera position.

Comment: @Crantisz Ahh you're right, I'll update it. Thank you.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hello, in case of an animated character, parts of the character(limbs, torso, head, etc) overlap relative to the viewpoint, meaning that in compositing for each part of the body two render layers would be required, one for the silhouette and one for the shape.

[Hopefully this image helps explain it.](https://i.imgur.com/WNQMLk9.png)
Imagine all the different possible combinations, each part of the body would require its own two layers: torso, head, upper right arm, lower right arm, etc... With a different character that got me to over 20 layers, with some simplifications.

Comment: "Object A inside of Object B" - you don't show one object inside another. Is there something inside the sphere that's supposed to be visible? Can you manually prepare the effect you're going for, for a still shot? What you managed so far isn't very helpful if it just doesn't work. Do you want to create some kind of a camouflage effect?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady In case of the sphere, it's inside of a subdivided cube. This cube is made visible at the start of the gif. The camera is being moved around to show the effect: the sphere's silhouette is being used as an alpha mask on the cube. Essentially, it's a realtime shader mask that works over a set distance.
Unfortunately because I'm using geometry nodes it is dependent on the amount of subdivisions and gives a jagged look when there aren't enough of them. I provided a file that you can check out. I have to think how I can best display it in a single image...

Comment: In case of a cuboid or any other mathematical object, it seems you can just create a UV mapping/mask in the shader. $$ $$ And what is the purpose of the standing person, what does it show? That you want a similar effect done for a character inside another character? 
$$ $$
It seems then, what you're doing is dynamic Eevee baking, and maybe should be described as such.

Comment: May I ask you - How is this thing useful? Some use case or final result to see benefit? ... I mean any try to project from camera view will result in weird result. Even discussion became quite long I still didn't get the purpose of all this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the Holdout object in front of the UV object and use the transparent ray depth on the uv object.

[image: Result]

Obviously, this will break if there are a varying number of transparent object in front of the camera.

1. Use Geometry Nodes to move the mask object between the UV object and the camera.
   [image: geo node setup]
   [image: mask object appears to be in front from]
   The mask object will appear to be in front of the UV object.
2. Add a transparent shader to the mask object.
3. Use the **Transparent Depth** as a condition for rendering the UV object transparent.
   [image: UV Object shader]

This only works in cycles rendered view. This hack can't be used for all objects at once sadly. Every instance of mask object and render object need to be rendered on a separate render layer.

[image]